# Watch root and check for new files in PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, inotify

I want to watch a folder from root of FTP. Automatically will be uploaded in the root some files. I need to know when this new file is uploaded and what I have to do is to get the name of the file and to add the name into the database with the file created.

I saw the people recommends to use inotify (Linux). But I can't understand if the code will be write in bash or in a simple php file..If can someone can help me with an example and full explanation

Here an example found on the internet

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
// directory to watch
$dirWatch = 'watch_dir';    
// Open an inotify instance
$inoInst = inotify_init();    
// this is needed so inotify_read while operate in non blocking mode
stream_set_blocking($inoInst, 0);    
// watch if a file is created or deleted in our directory to watch
$watch_id = inotify_add_watch($inoInst, $dirWatch, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);    
// not the best way but sufficient for this example :-)
while(true){    
  // read events (
  // which is non blocking because of our use of stream_set_blocking
  $events = inotify_read($inoInst);    
  // output data
  print_r($events);
}
// stop watching our directory
inotify_rm_watch($inoInst, $watch_id);    
// close our inotify instance
fclose($inoInst);
?>
```

Comment: "I can't understand if the code will be write in bash or in a simple php file" —  You found an example. It starts with `#!/usr/local/bin/php`. Doesn't that rather give the game away?

Comment: "If can someone can help me with an example and full explanation" — You've included both of those in the question. What, **specifically** don't you understand? Have you looked up the functions you don't understand in the PHP manual?

Comment: @Quentin i'm a junior ..and a very junion in linux and stuff like that. I don't know how to integrate..Look to the comment bellow..another way, Guest provide another solution

Answer (score -1):

A quick and dirty loop using an array could do it. Here's a bash example;

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/path/to/files/"
delay=60 #seconds to sleep between checks
#Get list of files already existing at startup:
for i in $dir*; do
    i="${i##*/}" #Isolates the file name from the path
    knownlist+=("$i")
done

while true; do
    sleep $delay
    for i in $dir*; do
        match=0
        i="${i##*/}"
        for ((ii=0;ii<${#knownlist[*]};ii++)); do
            if [[ $i == $ii ]]; then match=1; break; fi
            #Basically, for every file in $dir, we check against all files
            #listed in the ${knownfiles} array, to see if any match.
        done
        if [[ match == 0 ]]; then
            #No match was found, so this is a new file.
            #Place your database commands here; $i holds the file's name

            knownlist+=("$i") #File is now known, so we add it to the list
        fi
    done
done
```